# I am not getting the expected output for the following code:

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main (String[]args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n, money;
    String prodName = null;
    String minProdName = null;
    double price = 0.0;
    double total = 0.0;
    double min = 3000.0;

    System.out.println ("How much money do you have?");
    money = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println ("Please, insert the items in the invoice (the name of the product and its price) or enter stop to finish billing " );
     prodName = input.next();

    while (!(prodName.equals("stop")))
    {
        price = input.nextDouble();
        prodName = input.next();
        total = total +price;
    if (price<min && !(prodName.equals("stop")))
        {  
            min = price;
           minProdName = prodName;
        }

    }  
    if (total<money)
             System.out.println("You have enough money");
             System.out.println();

System.out.printf(" %s is the item with the minimum price(which is KD %.3f)", min);

}
}
```

I am always getting 'stop' as the output for product Name with Minimum price. How do I solve this issue?

Expected Output:
[image: Expected Output]

My Output:
[image: My Output]

Comment: @Jens that doesn't work it still gives me 'stop' as the output :/

Comment: Madhurya, Your output doesn't match your code.  Somehow, you are running code that's different from what you've shown here.  I think you should clean out your build directories and recompile everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.out.printf(" %s is the item with the minimum price(which is KD %.3f)", min);
```

Here you are passing only one value to get printed. You should pass two values here. First as a `String` and second as a `Double`.

So Change this line to

```
System.out.printf(" %s is the item with the minimum price(which is KD %.3f)", minProdName, min);
```