# My code is not working well

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NewClass {
public static void main(String[]args){ 
   Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    String productMin=""; 
   System.out.print("How much money do you have? ");
    double money=input.nextDouble();
      double minPrice=0;
         double total=0;
          double productPrice;
           System.out.print("Please, insert  the items in the invoice (the 
     name of product and its price):\n Insert \\\"stop\\\" as the name of 
     product to finish your input \n");
      String productName=input.next();
       productPrice=input.nextDouble();
       total=total+productPrice;

   while(!input.next().equals("stop"))
   {

     if(minPrice<productPrice)          
     {
       minPrice=productPrice;
       productMin=productName;

     }

    productName=input.next();
       total=total+productPrice; 
   }
   if(total<=money)
     {
       System.out.println("You have enough money !");
       System.out.printf("%s is the item with the minimum price(which is SR 
         %.3f)\n",productMin,minPrice);
   }
   else
       System.out.println("You don\'t have enough money");
   System.out.println(total);


     }//end of main method      
  }//end of calss
```

This is my code and it is not giving me the minimum price of the product and its name I tried a lot of things but still nothing and I'm running out of time can someone tell me where is the mistake????
This how the output should be

How much money do you have? 100 
Please, insert the items in the invoice (the name of product and its price): Insert \"stop\" as the name of product to finish your input
 Banana 20.200 
Water 15.300 
Honey 37.500 
stop 
You have enough money 
Water is the item with the minimum price (which is KD 15.300)

And this my output
How much money do you have? 100
Please, insert  the items in the invoice (the name of product and its price):
 Insert \"stop\" as the name of product to finish your input 
ss 20.100
dd 15.200
ff 37.500
stop
You have enough money !
ss is the item with the minimum price(which is SR 20.100)

Comment: Is it an assignment? Take a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43655206/i-am-not-getting-the-expected-output-for-the-following-code/43655334#43655334). Same Code. Same Question.

Comment: Yes it is . I traid to modify my code like  the one in the link you gave me it still did not work

Comment: For future reference, your question is missing helpful information including your expected output and your observed output. Please try to ask more complete questions in the future.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not bay attention .

Answer (score 0):

in this line

```
while(!input.next().equals("stop"))
```

what happens if the user did not enter `stop`? - he/she still entered something...

Comment: yes he  will keep entering the product name and its price until he enter stop

Comment: but where is the product name?? where is it stored ??

Comment: it is stored in the variable called productName

Comment: no, it is not. productName gets the **next** token (probably the price)

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot to take the product price as an input in your while loop, you are taking it as a string.

Comment: It'll give you a fatal logical error because you aren't performing the comparison in the right way, firstly you should edit your code to take a product price as a double in the while loop because if you didn't do that, the price will be entered in the productname String, secondly you could initialize minPrice with a big value say 999999999 and then compare the current product price with it inside your loop. Try to trace your code logic by printing the results using system out, it'll really help you.

Comment: I did then what ? :l

Comment: But its link here so that I can check it ::D